# Override Meta tags in Nextjs 13.4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

Hi I need to override my meta tag i.e. viewport meta tag. But when I am adding it in  tag it duplicates my viewport tag. How can I resolve it.

RootLayout.js

```
 <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
      </head>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
import './globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
  viewport: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1', // <-- here
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

To resolve your viewport issue, just modify the metadata as shown in the code above!

Comment: If i need to override some other meta tag the what should i doo

Comment: I believe it's just a matter of following the same process of reading the document and removing it at runtime. I think this could potentially impact your SEO, depending on the tag, but I assume it's only the viewport that is duplicating in your case. Could you add more tags there so that we can check if they will duplicate as well? That way, I can assist you better.

Comment: but how can i access the document object in my server side component. Is I need to convert it into client side ?

Comment: still showing the same issue

Comment: const metaViewports = head.querySelectorAll('meta[name="viewport"]');
This line of code gives me an empty array i.e. NodeList:[]

Comment: I found a better idea, do this to solve your viewport duplication issue; it will practically override it with the value you want. Add this inside your page:

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
  viewport: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'
}

Comment: Yeah it resolve my issue thanks....
But need to add these tags also
<meta property="og:title" content="ABC Blabla 2020 Friday" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://bla123.neocities.org/mp/friday.html" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Photo Album">
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="https://bla123.neocities.org/mp/images/thumbs/IMG_327.JPG"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" />
Do I simply need to put in head tag

Comment: And last thing I am not able to export metaData in client side components what is the solution to make dynamic title in every client side components

Comment: Hm, in this case, are you thinking of using custom meta tags per page, right? Perhaps there's a way to do it using the metadata, or you can create another specific RootLayout for that page with the headers. @AbhishekPoddar

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).